# Restore default page layout in memoir

Tags: margins, memoir, page

I managed to change the page layout (equal left/right margins) of a thesis' frontispiece with:

```
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

and now I'd like to restore memoir's default page layout.
How can I do that?

Comment: Not tested, but maybe you can do the previous change inside a group. (Inside \begingroup \endgroup) and then it could be restored without commands. Ask me to delete if not work

Comment: I don't think `memoir` supports different page layouts in the same document. You can do it with `geometry`, though. Do you know about `frontespizio`?

Comment: @koleygr can you please turn your comment into an answer? it seems to work!

Comment: @egreg I successfully used `frontespizio` in the past! :)
However, the title page required for my doctoral thesis is not easy to reproduce with `frontespizio`, and I opted for a manual reproduction of the word template provided by the university ;)

Comment: I've found `frontespizio` very flexible. Is there a *specimen* for the title page?

Comment: Do just the titlepage as a standalone document and include it using package `pdfpages`. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#Integrating_the_title_page

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/363840/37907

Comment: @egreg here it is! http://www2.units.it/dott/files/EFFronte.doc

Comment: And I told you that `frontespizio` is *very* flexible. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg `memoir` supports different page layouts just like other classes do. I'm sure that I've said this before but can't recall where. If a document is onecolumn then `\twocolumn`  *make your changes* `\onecolumn`. For a twocolumn document reverse the column change macros. (I got this from Donald Arseneau  many years ago.) It works because LaTeX recalculates the layout whenever there is a switch between one and two columns.

Answer (score 2):

In latex, it is possible to make temporary changes or change temporary some variables by using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` and do our changes between these two commands.

I am answering from a mobile and will improve the answer later.

In your case a `\begingroup` before the layout change and an `\endgroup` at the point you want to undo, could work, but be careful to redefine whatever variable possibly defined inside this group without `\global` or equivalent definition

Comment: Generally speaking you are right, but changing, for example. margins and textwidth, is problematic. TeX sets type using a specific layout, until the current page overflows. It then cuts off the current page and puts any cutoff text at the top of the next page WITHOUT CHANGING THE LAYOUT for that bit of text. It may then change the layout on the page for succeeding text. In general the layout can only be changed after the text for a page has been completely output and before the text for the following page is started.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to the specific problem, but here's how you can use `frontespizio`, given the template at http://www2.units.it/dott/files/EFFronte.doc

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[norules,noadvisor]{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontespizio}
\begin{Preambolo*}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\renewcommand{\frontinstitutionfont}{\fontsize{22}{24}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\frontdivisionfont}{\fontsize{18}{24}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\fronttitlefont}{\fontsize{20}{24}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\frontsubtitlefont}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\frontnamesfont}{\fontsize{14}{18}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\frontfootfont}{\fontsize{14}{18}\bfseries}
\end{Preambolo*}
\Logo[3cm]{trieste}
\Istituzione{UNIVERSIT\`A DEGLI STUDI DI TRIESTE}
\Divisione{XLII CICLO DEL DOTTORATO DI RICERCA IN}
\Scuola{PENNUTISTICA}
\Titolo{TITOLO DELLA TESI}
\Sottotitolo{Settore scientifico-disciplinare: PEN/99}

\NCandidato{}
\Candidato{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \normalfont DOTTORANDO \\
  \bfseries Alessandro Cuttin\\[2ex]
  \normalfont COORDINATORE \\
  \bfseries PROF. Frederick Frankenstein \\[2ex]
  \normalfont SUPERVISORE DI TESI \\
  \bfseries PROF. The Monster
  \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}}
\Piede{ANNO ACCADEMICO 2017/2018}
\end{frontespizio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well, thank you very much!
I'll try to put it in the document before the submission :)

Comment: Pennutistica? :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX The more general area including duckology, of course.

Comment: @egreg I suspected it, LOL!

Answer (score 1):

The general method of changing a document's layout in the middle of it is:

```
\documentclass[...]{report}% or book or article or ...
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\twocolumn% if onecolumn document
% make your layout changes here
\onecolumn% if onecolumn document
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This is because LaTeX recalculates the layout parameters when switching between one and two columns (I don't know about the `multicolumn` package).
I originally got this many years ago from Donald Arseneau.

For the `memoir` class, as an example:

```
\documentclass[,...]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% change the layout if you wish
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\twocolumn
\setlrmarginsandblock{3in}{*}{1}% increase the margins & reduce text width
\checkandfixthelayout
\onecolumn
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

To get the details of `memoir`'s original layout you could simply process:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

which will print all the values on the terminal.