# Top margin variation does not affect title position

Tags: memoir, titlesec, geometry

The idea behind the `memoir`-based setup below is that the title should be confined in the setting of the `\newgeometry`, while the image should span the whole width of the title page sitting at its bottom, and the remainder of the pages should follow `\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}`. I'd like to arbitrarily move the title up and/or down. But changing the `top` margin in my `\newgeometry` does not affect the vertical positioning of the title. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openany, final]{memoir}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \newcommand\YUGE{\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont}
    \setlength{\paperwidth}{\stockwidth}
    \afterpage{\restoregeometry}
    \newgeometry{left=1.5in, right=1in,top=-2in, bottom=0in}
    \definecolor{mytan}{HTML}{628ab1}
    \pagecolor{mytan}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
    
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \YUGE \textbf{The title}
    \end{flushleft}
    \vspace{8cm}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[scope fading=north, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]{
            \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}
        };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \endgroup
    \clearpage
    \chapter{My chapter}
    \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I needed something similar, and I solved it with `\changepage` macro of `changepage` package. (Perhaps because `\newgeometry` did not work with memoir).

Comment: See also the solutions proposed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284486/set-a-different-layout-for-a-single-page-in-memoir